# vc-mode doesn't evaluate when mode-line-format is set with setq-default

Tags: mode-line, mode-line-format, setq, vc-mode, setq-default

I've this code in my `init.el`

```el
(setq-default mode-line-format (list
                                (propertize " %b " 'face 'bufname)
                                (propertize (concat " " vc-mode " ") 'face 'gitmode)))
```

This evaluates `vc-mode` to [""](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82KS2.png)

[image: undesired behaviour]

while evaluating the same thing with `setq` instead of `setq-default` results in the desired string ["Git:nixos"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAwes.png).

[image: desired behaviour]

But I need to use `setq-default` here to modify the `mode-line-format`. Why does this happen and how to fix it?

Comment: You shouldn’t ask two questions at the same time; move the second one to its own Question.

Comment: edited, the second one wasn't that important anyway

Comment: You're not using a good value for `mode-line-format`. Read the Elisp manual about it. For one thing, you need to quote a variable such as `vc-mode`. For another you should use `:propertize` (see Properties in Mode). You can look this up as easily as anyone who might want to provide an answer - just check what the manual tells you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the code in your init file runs, there are no open files at all. `vc-mode` is only set when a file is finally opened and determined to be in version–controlled. This means that when it runs your init file and evaluates `vc-mode`, it puts the `nil` value into the list that goes into `mode-line-format`. That `nil` is then skipped whenever the mode line is displayed.

Instead, you should put the symbol `'vc-mode` into the `mode-line-format`. Then, when the mode line is displayed, it will know to put the current value of the variable named by that symbol into the mode line instead. Like this:

```
(setq-default mode-line-format
              (list
               (propertize " %b " 'face 'bufname)
               (propertize " " 'face 'gitmode)
               (propertize 'vc-mode 'face 'gitmode)
               (propertize " " 'face 'gitmode)))
```

The `'` in front of the name is called a quote, and it quotes whatever lisp form follows it so that it is treated literally instead of evaluated. The `propertize` function, for example, wants the symbol `'face` rather than the value of a variable that happens to be called `face`, so it too is quoted.

It also doesn’t matter whether you use `setq` or `setq-default` in your init file, since at that point there are no open buffers and so setting any variable will set the default value of that variable rather than the buffer–local value.

Finally, the mode line machinery has a lot of useful things that can simplify your code quite a bit, like this:

```
(setq mode-line-format
      '((:propertize " %b " face bufname)
        (:propertize (" " vc-mode " ") face gitmode)))
```

You should read [chapter 23.4.2 The Data Structure of the Mode Line](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Mode-Line-Data.html) of the Emacs Lisp manual, which details everything that can go into the mode line. This manual is also available inside of Emacs. You can open the Info viewer with `C-h i`; this starts you out at a menu of all the manuals installed on your system.

Comment: +1 - nice answer!

Comment: thanks, the referenced chapter saved me a lot of time with some other stuff too